# Enable third parties to upgrade Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu version from 14.04 to available newer version.
I have enabled all the required upgrade options But I still get this error. "Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager."

[image: Settings Image 1]

[image: Settings Image 2]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mbFai.png

http://i.stack.imgur.com/r5r6d.png

Comment: What were you doing when you get this error?

Comment: ehm please explain your problem? what I see here is normal. intended and correct. PPA's need to be -disabled- before an upgrade.

Comment: I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu version from 14.04 to available new version (15.10).

Comment: That is not possible. 15.04 has gone end of life so the upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 to 15.10 has been cut of. But what does that have to do with above question about PPAs? For an upgrade you need to disable ppa's and  the system will do that automatically. If you want an upgrade from 14.04 wait for 16.04 (an lts to lts will be possible when 16.04.2 arrives)